# Reducing integrals over abstract spaces to integrals on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am studying for a measure-theoretic based course in probability theory and I am stuck on a theorem that goes as follows.

**Definition**

First, it defines a measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$ to be *standard* if it is isomorphic to
$(F,\mathcal{B}_F)$ for some Borel subset $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Theorem**

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a standard measurable space. Let $\mu$ be a
$\Sigma$-finite measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ and put $b=\mu(E)$, possibly $+\infty$. Then, there
exists a mapping $h$ from $[0, b)$ into $E$, measurable relative to $\mathcal{B}_{[0,b)}$ and $E$,
such that
\begin{equation*}
\mu=\lambda \circ h^{-1}
\end{equation*}

My issue is that the textbook does not give a full proof of this theorem. It does give a sort of proof, but one that relies on the result of an exercise (where $(E,\mathcal{E})=\big(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathcal{B}({\mathbb{R}_+})\big)$, $\mu$ is left unspecified, and $h^{-1}$ is replaced by the cumulative distribution function) which is not solved. So I am missing a crucial piece.
I worked out such exercise at the best of my possibilities, but I can only get the result under the assumption that the cumulative distribution function is never constant (i.e., it is strictly increasing), so I do not have a proof under more general assumptions.

This theorem is not even given a name in the textbook, which makes it more difficult for me to find it (and a proof) elsewhere. I assume there is a textbook with a formal and full proof of this important result.

If you could give me a proof of this, it would be incredibly helpful, but even just a reference to a source containing a full proof (or a name for the theorem) would be great. Thanks to everyone who can consider replying.

Comment: Could you perhaps be looking for the distribution function? I am reading page 172 of Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin (easy to find online) now and he uses this function to reduce integrals over arbitrary $\sigma$-finite positive measure spaces to integrals over $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, although I see a derivative in the statement of the theorem, so I guess this could be a slightly different version of that theorem, although it is meant to reduce integrals on abstract spaces to integrals on the real line with respect to the Lebesgue measure.